# Updating Field schema has no effects

Tags: 2013

I'm trying to change display pattern on field by modifying field schema - I've got nothing while doing that on list field, but I've successfully update global field schema with same name. Any suggestions?

Here is some code:

```
SPField preview = list.Fields["Preview"];
SPField encAbsWebImgUrl = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("EncodedAbsWebImgUrl");
SPField miniImage = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("MiniImage");
preview.SchemaXml = Regex.Replace(preview.SchemaXml, encAbsWebImgUrl.InternalName, miniImage.InternalName, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the field aswell using

```
preview.Update(true);
```

as referenced here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.update(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.update%28v=office.14%29.aspx) , to actually save the changes.

Comment: I've used that method without effects.

Comment: OK, try also updating the list: list.Update()

Comment: I've tried that method, but it also haven't any effects - a schema doesn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to set the web.AllowUnsafeUpdate = true, then preview.Update, then set AllowUnsafeUpdate = false ?

Comment: Would make sense in some cases but not outside of an event receiver and not on other objects than files and list items